# Tree not occupying entire parent composite

Tags: java, layout, tree, swt

I am trying to display a SWT `Tree` in a `Group` composite within a `SashForm`. The SWT Tree is not filling up the entire Group composite on startup, but it does, once I re-size the SashForm. I am getting correct functioning, i.e. the tree is occupying entire Group composite. Could anyone help me out?

```
    sashForm = new SashForm(parent, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SMOOTH | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    sashForm.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));

    explainStepsGroup = new Group(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    explainStepsGroup.setText("Explain Steps");
    GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL,SWT.FILL,true,true);
    explainStepsGroup.setLayoutData(gd);
    explainStepsGroup.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    tree = new Tree(explainStepsGroup, SWT.BORDER);
    tree.setLayout(new FillLayout());       
    tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
    tree.setToolTipText("Steps");
    ...
    ...
    void fillTreeItems() {  
    TreeItem rootTreeItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NULL);
    rootTreeItem.setText("Steps");
    rootTreeItem.setExpanded(true); 

    TreeItem stepNumTreeItem = null;
    TreeItem stepTextItem = null;

    stepList = m_explainModel.getStepText();
    Iterator<String> iter = stepList.keySet().iterator();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
    stepNumTreeItem = new TreeItem(rootTreeItem, SWT.NULL);
    String stepNum = iter.next();
    stepNumTreeItem.setText(stepNum.toString());
    stepNumTreeItem.setExpanded(false); 

    stepTextItem = new TreeItem(stepNumTreeItem, SWT.WRAP);
    stepTextItem.setText(stepList.get(stepNum));
    tree.showItem(stepNumTreeItem); 

    }
    tree.setRedraw(true);
    tree.pack();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

These problems are usually hard to figure out. The first question you need to answer is: Which control isn't resizing?

You assume it's the tree but that is only because you can't see the group. So maybe the tree is filling the group but the group doesn't fill the sash.

The first thing to do is to give everything a border or a distinct background color. That way, you can see where each control is and how big it is.

That should give you an idea. From the code, this line is useless:

```
tree.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```

Tree uses it's own, fixed layout to lay out its children. Also, you're not setting a layout for the `SashForm`, so it won't change the size of its children. Try

```
sashForm.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```

[as per this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Createasashformwiththreechildren.htm).

Related: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) - Old but still true.

Comment: +1 for the link. Every SWT programmer should have read that article.

Comment: Group is filling the sash correctly.. But Tree control is not filling Group correctly..

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting any `GridData` on the `Tree`. Try the sample code below:

```
public class Dummy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("Dummy window");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        SashForm sashForm = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.SMOOTH | SWT.H_SCROLL);
        sashForm.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        Group firstGroup = new Group(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
        firstGroup.setText("Upper");
        firstGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        firstGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Tree tree = new Tree(firstGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        tree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
        tree.setToolTipText("Steps");

        fillTreeItems(tree);

        Group secondGroup = new Group(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
        secondGroup.setText("Lower");
        secondGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        secondGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Tree secondTree = new Tree(secondGroup, SWT.BORDER);
        secondTree.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        secondTree.setHeaderVisible(true);
        secondTree.setToolTipText("Steps");

        fillTreeItems(secondTree);

        shell.pack();
        shell.setSize(400, 200);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void fillTreeItems(Tree tree)
    {
        TreeItem rootTreeItem = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NULL);
        rootTreeItem.setText("Steps");
        rootTreeItem.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem item = new TreeItem(rootTreeItem, SWT.NULL);
        item.setText("item");
        item.setExpanded(false);

        tree.pack();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks after starting:

[image]

And after moving the `Sash`:

[image]

Comment: @rohitha Did you try the code above? Keep in mind that I changed the other `GridData`s and `Layout`s as well. So you will have to do the same in your code.

Comment: I am developing Eclipse RCP application.. As part of that, I need to invoke a menu from SQL scrapbook which opens a View containing above sais Tree. when I change perspective, Tree is correctly occupying the Group composite but not for the first time when invoked from SQL editor menu.. What makes the layout adjust/redraw when I change the perspective so that Tree is occupying the entire Group composite? I cannot post an image .. since new users are restricted..

Comment: @rohitha You can add the link to the image to your question and I will include it as an image.

Comment: Problem solved.. I called explainStepsGroup.layout(true); at the end of fillTreeItems() method after tree.pack() statement..      Thanks for the replies..

Comment: @rohitha Nevertheless, read this: [Understanding Layouts in SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html)